# how to retrieve whole string space separated in php variable from html options?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Select tag takes options from mysql database. Then when the value is assigned to php variable and echo is done, then only first part of text is shown.

**For example  :**

> option:- vijay sharma
>   echo output:- vijay

```html
<select name="facultyname" onchange="myFunction(this.value)" id="facultyname">
  <?php 
    if(!$link) { die( ''.mysql_error()); } 
      //for facultyname fname is facultname 
      $query="SELECT DISTINCT(fname) FROM faculty WHERE 1" ;
      $result=m ysqli_query ($link,$query);
      echo "<option>Dropdown</option>";
      while($r=m ysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value=".$r[ 'fname']. ">".$r[ 'fname']. "</option>";
      }
      echo "";
  ?>
</select>

<?php $facultyname=$_POST[ "facultyname"]; echo $facultyname; ?>
```

Comment: Could you show us some code?

Comment: Try to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`.

Comment: Love the where clause. Are u new at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a lack of quotes.

Change

```
echo "<option value=".$r[ 'fname']. ">".$r[ 'fname']. "</option>";
```

to

```
echo '<option value="'.$r['fname']. '">'.$r['fname']. '</option>';
```

or

```
echo "<option value=\"".$r['fname']. "\">".$r['fname']. "</option>";
```

the view-source needs to show

```
<option value="vijay sharma">vijay sharma</option>
```

and not

```
<option value=vijay sharma>vijay sharma</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember about escaping your option.value string:

```
<option value="A "B" C">A "B" C</option>
```

is not what you want.